# Almacenar Consulta SQL SERVER en un Array

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una consulta donde pretendo almacenar el resultado de una consulta en un arreglo pero no logro almacenarlo, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

    global $AMBIENTE;
    session_start();
    require_once 'Functions.php';

    $CONEXION = fnConexionBancaCorporativa($AMBIENTE);
    $data = array();

    $query = "SELECT AREA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AREA) AS ID, FORMAT(FECHA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FECHA, SIGNOFF FROM TSIGNOFF GROUP BY AREA, FECHA, SIGNOFF ORDER BY FECHA";
    $RESULTADO = sqlsrv_query($CONEXION, $query);
    $REGISTROS = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RESULTADO);
    foreach ($REGISTROS as $row)
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row["ID"],
            'title' => $row["SIGNOFF"],
            'start' => $row["FECHA"],
            'end' => $row["FECHA"]
        );
}

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Los errores que me arroja la consola es algo como lo siguiente:
:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'SIGNOFF'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'FECHA'

Al final la consola de Google me muestra lo siguiente:

> `[{"id":"C","title":"C","start":"C","end":"C"},{"id":"C","title":"C","start":"C","end":"C"},{"id":"1","title":"1","start":"1","end":"1"},{"id":"1","title":"1","start":"1","end":"1"},{"id":"0","title":"0","start":"0","end":"0"},{"id":"0","title":"0","start":"0","end":"0"},{"id":"S","title":"S","start":"S","end":"S"},{"id":"S","title":"S","start":"S","end":"S"}]`

La consulta a la base de datos muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si mira es que la fecha la detecta como objeto, le tienes que dar formato para que la pueda leer php

quedaria asi

```
session_start();
require_once 'Functions.php';

$CONEXION = fnConexionBancaCorporativa($AMBIENTE);

$query = "SELECT AREA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AREA) AS ID, FORMAT(FECHA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FECHA, SIGNOFF FROM TSIGNOFF GROUP BY AREA, FECHA, SIGNOFF ORDER BY FECHA";

$RESULTADO  = sqlsrv_query($CONEXION, $query);
if ($RESULTADO ) {
    while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RESULTADO , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $filas[] = $rows;
    }
    sqlsrv_close($CONEXION );

    if (isset($filas)) {
        return $filas;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
} else {
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
}
```

Y para mostrar los datos serian asi:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($file) ; $i++){
echo $file[$i]['FECHA']->format('d-m-Y');
echo $file[$i]['AREA'];
}
```

ya con ese dato asi y los demas como los tienes para que los muestre
Suerte!

Comment: Maravillosamente resulto útil. Gracias

Comment: de que!, que bueno que te fue util, mucha suerte!